# Delayed Execution on Edit with Google Apps Script

Tags: triggers, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, delayed-execution

I have a relatively large spreadsheet (300 rows, 30 columns) that I color based on the values in the spreadsheet. I'm doing accessing the API minimally using only two accesses:

- `getValues(...)` to access all the values of the data range.
- `setBackgrounds(...)` to set all the backgrounds of the data range.

This runs in about half a second or less. However, it gets in the way if I make it run on every edit using `onEdit()`, but I also don't want it to be updated at regular time intervals when I'm not editing it, seems like a waste. Is there a good way to make the script run in a "delayed" way, updating at regular time intervals while I'm editing?

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I would say you should look at Google Sheets' conditional formatting (Format > Conditional formatting menu item in Sheets) -- you may be able to do much of what you need without involving Apps Script at all.

Failing that, you can set up a [regular time-based trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) to check for edits and change the backgrounds appropriately. You can support this trigger with a separate onEdit() trigger to record what has changed internally. The flow goes like this:

1. A change is made and onEdit() triggers
2. The onEdit() trigger only records the changed cell locations to a local variable or Cache
3. A time-based trigger fires every minute/hour/whenever
4. The time-based trigger checks the cache for edited cells, alters their backgrounds, then clears them from the cache

That said, depending on your workflow this approach may not be much better than simply using a time trigger to change the cells directly.

Comment: From what I understand ,a simple flag telling that an edit has been made would be sufficient to allow the timer trigger execution. No need to remember the modified cells since the OP uses a global sheet update. Otherwise I agree that this would be the appropriate approach.