# Formatting Cells to highlight after a specific time period has elapsed

Tags: scripting, google-sheets-api, gs-conditional-formatting

I am trying to resolve an issue regarding my workplace in google sheets. I am looking to highlight cells in a specific column after a specific time has elapsed. This column is going to consist of time stamps. What I am trying to do is once 15 minutes of the cell's timestamp to highlight it red as a notifier for the user of the sheet to proceed with a process. There is no way to do this with normal Conditional formatting and look clean. I am not sure as to where to start other than I can basically do this by making a script using Google Sheets script editor. I just need a push in the direction.

I have looked into normal Conditional Formatting built into Google Sheets and it can be done but you would have an End Time Column basically incremented 15 minutes after the original time stamp using the today() formula. However this is cluttered and ideally isn't as seemless I would like it to be.

I am looking to write a script to automatically highlight the timestamp red once the current time is at least 15 minutes or older. Without the end column it doesn't work and ultimately I am trying to keep from having extra columns when they are not needed. I am not sure where to start. Just looking for opinions on how to start this.

Comment: Can I ask you about your goal? About ``What I am trying to do is once 15 minutes of the cell's timestamp to highlight it red as a notifier for the user of the sheet to proceed with a process.``, you want to change the backgroundcolor of a cell 15 minutes after a timestamp was manually put to a cell. You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26683298/10971581 ?